# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Radio Button list using Editor Templates: Model is not complete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I have to implement multiple Radio Button List on a web page (ASP.NET MVC 4).
For that, i have used Editor Templates.

Here is the code:

```
public class Evaluation
{
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    public Evaluation()
    {
        Questions = new List<Question>();
    }
}

    public class Question
    {
     private string _name;
     private string _translationText;

     public int LocalizationID { get; set; }
     public string Name
     {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
     }
     public string TranslationText
     {
        get
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_translationText))
            {
                return _name;
            }
            else
                return _translationText;
        }
        set { _translationText = value; }
     }
     public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public int SelectedAnswer { get; set; }
     public int Order { get; set; }

     public Question()
     {
        Answers = new List<Answer>();
     }
 }
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            var evaluation = _service.GetEvaluation();

            return View(evaluation);
        }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Evaluation model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          //Save Evaluation 
        }
       retrun View(model);
    }
```

If the model is not valid, that should return me on the main view with the model. But the model is not complete and contains only the info the LocalizationID and SelectedAnswer:

**View**

Index.chtml

```
@model Evaluation

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Questions)

    @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Questions)

     <p>
        @Html.Raw(Html.GenerateCaptcha())
        @Html.ValidationMessage("recaptcha")
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="@T("Save_Answer")"/>

    @Html.ValidationMessage("ERROR_SURVEY")
}
```

In the Editor Templates:

```
  @model Question

<div id="@Model.LocalizationID">
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.LocalizationID)
    <h3>@Model.Order. @Model.TranslationText</h3>



    @if (Model.Order == 1)
    {
        <p>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(b => b.SelectedAnswer,new SelectList(Model.Answers,"LocalizationID","TranslationText"))

        </p> 
    } 
    else
    {
        foreach (var a in Model.Answers)
        {
            <p>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(b=>b.SelectedAnswer, a.LocalizationID ) @a.TranslationText
            </p>
        }
    }

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=> x.SelectedAnswer)
</div>
```

As i'm really new in ASP.NET MVC, I took the code from : [ASP.NET MVC 3 Radio Button Strongly typed](https://github.com/kshyju/ASP.MVC3-Radio-button-list)

Is there any solution for having back my model ? I need it to avoid any refresh of my page and losing the selected options.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to regenerate your model from your service on each web request in order to fill in the properties that are one-way controller-to-view. For all the round-trip properties of your model (e.g. `SelectedAnswer`), you need to map the new values that have been posted into the generated view model.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Evaluation inputModel)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     //Save Evaluation 
   }

   var outputModel = _service.GetEvaluation();

   for(var i = 0; i < outputModel.Questions.Count; i++)
       outputModel.Questions[i].SelectedAnswer = inputModel.Questions[i].SelectedAnswer;

   return View(outputModel);
}
```

Another, more advanced but cleaner, way to achieve this is to implement a custom model binder for `Evaluation` and use that to fill in data acquired from your service.

Comment: Thanks, that's working. I was expecting some default functionnality or so coming with ASP.NET MVC :)

Comment: @fix105 There's really very few sensible things MVC could do for you in this case: if part of your model comes from a database or a service or a cache, and you are not roundtripping it via the client, you have to go and get it on each request.

Comment: @fix105 I added an alternative which gives a cleaner approach and would make your controllers look more like you would expect.